# how to run test in certain cases?

Tags: node.js, testing, backend, tdd, web-testing

I'm new to TDD and I wrote a few test functions that check the sign up and deletion of the user , but before each running i go to the database and delete the user before testing the sign up and i go to the database to put a dummy user info before deletion so my question is how does this thing run in actual production environment , like every time I want to run the tests , I go to the database and make all these modification , what if user signed up with the below credentials then the test would return 200 ?? (i use jest with nodejs e2e)

````
describe("given user is not found", () => {
      it("should return 404", async () => {
        await request(app)
          .post("/api/v1/auth/signIn")
          .send({
            email: "s@gmail.com",
            password: "s",
          })
          .expect(404);
      });
    });```
````

Answer (score 0):

Other opinions are available but here's what I'd do.

Let's assume your backend is in java. Before I wrote any code I would have a test that called the API endpoint with the same input and expected a 404.

Some will tell you to mock the database with a library like Mockito but I don't think that's necessary. For our purposes a database is nothing but a map. A map takes an id and returns an object. So make an interface that describes interactions with your database, saveUser(), loadUser() - that kind of thing. Implement the interface with your real implementation. And implement it with your test one which is just a class with those same methods and a map for actually doing real work. This is called a fake.

Your api could return a 404 if the user is not found or a 200 if it is. Your test is in the backend and its quicker than it was before because you're not hitting a real database.

As far as your example goes I really don't think you need to set anything up in the database at all. But if you absolutely must then you could have an endpoint which tears down the database setup and sets it up again, which is executed at the start of the test. Or a database image that you stand up just for the test. Both are probably overkill.

Comment: Adding some code to help out the OP would be a great way to improve your answer! :)